# Applying a formula to multiple columns, across multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to apply the `=LOWERCASE()` formula to four columns (J, O, T, and Y) across multiple sheets in the same workbook.

Here's the VBA code I have so far, it is applying to the right columns, but it's returning an error for each.

```
Sub Clean_Lowercase()
Const N As Integer = 1
Dim r As Long, i As Integer, X As Integer, t As Long
Dim rng As Range, r As Range
Dim v As Variant
v = Array("J", "O", "T", "Y")
t = 1
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
r = Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count
For X = 0 To UBound(v)
    Set rng = Sheets(i).Range(v(X) & N & ":" & v(X) & r)
    For Each r In rng
        r.Formula = "=LOWERCASE()"
Next
Next
End Sub
```

I am very new to VBA coding, any suggestions is greatly appreciated! I really want to learn.

Many thanks!

Comment: You are trying to insert a formula that will overwrite the data with the actual formula, and the formula needs a reference.  If you are trying to change the data in the cell to lower case then `r.Value = Lcase$(r.Value)`

Comment: Ah, okay! Should I insert `r.Value = Lcase&(r.Value)` in place of `r.Formula`?

Comment: yes, but it is `Lcase$(r.Value)`

Comment: Oops, yes, `$` instead of `&`. Thanks for the catch! I tried a run and it prompted a "compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope" for the `r As Range`?

Comment: What is the LowerCase formula - is it a recent addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this.

1. You are using the `r` twice, once as a Long, once az a Range.
2. The `For Each` loop's `Next` is missing
3. The formula needs a reference of what would you like to set to lowercase.
   For example, if you want to have the lowercase value of the left neightbouring cells, you should write: `=LOWERCASE(R[1]C[-1])`
4. Sheets are a 1 based collection, so if you write `For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1,` the last sheet wont be processed (maybe this is intentional?) and the code will throw an error at the first sheet (no sheets(0) exist)

Something like this works:

```
Sub Clean_Lowercase()
    Const N As Integer = 1
    Dim r As Long, i As Integer, X As Integer, t As Long
    Dim rng As Range, ri As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Array("J", "O", "T", "Y")
    t = 1
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        r = Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For X = 0 To UBound(v)
            Set rng = Sheets(i).Range(v(X) & N & ":" & v(X) & r)
            For Each ri In rng
                ri.Formula = "=LOWERCASE(R[1]C[-1])"
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! These modifications, along with u/Scott Craner's comment, made the code work!